# How can I add entries to generated to_entries?

Tags: jq

I have this json:

```json
{
  "idTypes":"type1|type2|type3",
  "idValues":"xxx|yyy|zzz"
}
```

I need to reshape this information to:

```json
{
  "idType": "type1",
  "idValue": "xxxx"
}
{
  "idType": "type2",
  "idValue": "yyyy"
}
{
  "idType": "type1",
  "idValue": "zzzz"
}
```

Up to now I've tried with this ([click jqplay here](https://jqplay.org/s/7pp-Hx_lsd)):

```
.idTypes| split("|") | to_entries[]
```

But it doesn't generate what I need:

```json
{
  "key": 0,
  "value": "type1"
}
{
  "key": 1,
  "value": "type2"
}
{
  "key": 2,
  "value": "type3"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
to_entries | map(.value | split("|")) | transpose[] | {"idType": .[0], "idValue": .[1] }
```

Will generate

```json
{
  "idType": "type1",
  "idValue": "xxx"
}
{
  "idType": "type2",
  "idValue": "yyy"
}
{
  "idType": "type3",
  "idValue": "zzz"
}
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OsV0cV8rHF).

---

Regarding `transpose` please read [jq's docs about this](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#transpose).